# Protobuf serialization for XML

Tags: xml, base64, protocol-buffers

As a POC, I was looking into the possibility to benefit from the supposed speed and low memory (network) footprint of Protobuf serialization in my XML webservice.

So instead of producing messages like:

```
<message>
  <author>Bob</author>
  <text>Hello John!</text>
  <date>1351875211751</date>
</message>
```

I would produce things like

```
<message>Cg5IZWxsbyBVbmtub3duIRIEQmlsbBiGteSPrCc=</message>
```

with a base64 encoding of my Protobuf message. Now, wouldn't the introduction of a base64 layer ruin the whole purpose (speed and bandwidth saving) of using Protobuf?

Comment: As someone who has to consume a lot of web APIs, this sort of thing makes me want to die. I'd much rather you expose an XML interface that takes XML (no protobuf) as well as a protobuf interface that takes a protobuf message (no XML). `Content-Type` and `Accept` headers let clients and servers collectively negotiate exactly this sort of thing.

Comment: Everything @willglynn said. Base-64 is a compromise for when you need binary on something that only takes text. I echo the use of request headers (or even a separate endpoint if that isn't possible) to choose between formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments and answers.

I realize there is actually no point in keeping an XML enveloppe over my binary serialized message, except keeping the stack of technologies I am familiar with. In this case it just forces me to convert an optimized binary stream into a base64 (or other text) string.

If I want to test or use Protobuf, I'd better test it all alone instead of wrapping it into another layer of xml and base64. Instead of exposing an XML webservice, I will need to expose a service with a content-type such as "application/octet-stream" or "application/x-google-protobuf"

Answer (score 3):

> Now, wouldn't the introduction of a base64 layer ruin the whole purpose (speed and bandwidth saving) of using Protobuf?

It depends on the data. If you have a small number of fields with short names and a lot of data per value, then yes, it will be bigger.

If you have a *large* number of fields with *short* values, then the size of the XML tags will overwhelm the data. For example:

```
<message>
  <verylongname1>x</verylongname1>
  <verylongname2>y</verylongname2>
  <verylongname3>z</verylongname3>
</message>
```

In protobuf format, that would be just a few bytes per field, compared with a lot of per-field overhead due to having the name twice in XML. Even multiplying the data size by the constant 4/3 for base64 encoding, you'd still be better off.

That's assuming there's no compression, of course. If you compress the XML, a lot of the downsides would go away - whereas I wouldn't expect the base64 protobuf to compress nearly as well. We don't know whether you use compression, mind you.

You should also consider the diagnostic appeal of XML - no need to run the data through a base64 decoder followed by a protobuf printer.

Bottom line: this depends on your data and exactly what you're doing with it. There are other serialization schemes beyond XML and protobuf, of course. Consider json, for example...